# Catching and reacting to a warning

Tags: interruption, error-trapping

I have a program which can lead in certain cases to a division by zero. I would like to know if there is a way in *Mathematica* to make a conditional statement like the following one:

```
If[Warning == Power:: infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered, something, somethingelse]
```

As it is a complex piece of code borrowed from an old Paper from the *Mathematica Journal*, I would like not to search exactly what line is the cause of the warning and program what to do in this case.

Comment: You might be interested in [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html), which seems to do what you want; also of interest might be the [Interrupts and Aborts Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InterruptsAndAborts.html).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following contrived example:

```
Clear[fun]
fun := If[EvenQ@RandomInteger[{1, 20}], 1/0, "Success"]

Quiet@Check[fun, "FAILED", {Power::infy}]
```

This function will generate a division by zero roughly half the time, randomly. You can evaluate it a few times, and you will see that when the division by zero happens, `Quiet` prevents the message from being displayed, but you still get the `"FAILED"` output to indicate the problem, which you can replace with whatever makes sense for you in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot so my question was not so stupid !